# HTML/CSS: Div elements not functioning as intended

Tags: html, css

I'm new to web development and I was working on a portfolio page for Freecodecamp. The problem I have right now is in regards to `div` elements. At the bottom of my HTML code there is a `div` element (ie `background-color: #00dfff`) that is not functioning the way I intended. No matter what I do in regards to debugging, when I run the code the last `div` element either shows up behind my second `div` element or within my third `div` element. Could someone help me find my error/bug?

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div style= "width:250px; height: 50px; margin: 0 auto;  background-color:#1DCB9E; color:white;" >
      <h1 align="center"> William Fisher</h1>
    </div>
    <div style= "float:left; width:1000px; height: 320px; margin: 0 auto; margin-top: 20px; margin-left: 50px;  background-color:#1DCB69; color:white; "> <img class="pic-one" align="right" src="https://s10.postimg.org/7aewtk3kp/Bill_in_China_One.jpg">
      <h2 align="center"> Chinese > English Translator (And an Aspiring Computer Scientist) </h2>
      <p style="font-size:22px;"> Hello! My name is William and I am a part-time Chinese to English translator who has worked with companies such as Gengo and Yeeyan. I have a broad range of experience in translating projects such as documentary scripts, brochures, government documents, questionnaires, business correspondence, and academic articles. I am currently a student at UNCA and I am studying Computer Science. I hope to enter the field of Natural Language Processing in the future and apply my knowledge to the development of machine translation applications. </p>
    </div>
    <div style= "float:right; width:1000px; height: 375px; margin: 0 auto; margin-top: 20px; margin-right: 50px;  background-color:#CB1D54; color:white;">
      <h2 align="center"> Chinese to English Translation Portfolio </h2>
      <div><a href="https://docs.google.com/document/d/1J2noa4KbzNh_fT2uPXd0Qp3Z1eWcuBxzOALuQ7_8j0k/edit?usp=sharing"><img src="https://s9.postimg.org/6ov06a80f/Screenshot_3.png" width="25%" height="25%" style="float:left; margin-right:5px; margin-left: 120px;"></a> </div>
      <div><a href="https://docs.google.com/document/d/1IsG6BiUluUpVgaM71V8LaXH_qd3kJmNMnWBVZDIhL1U/edit?usp=sharing"><img src="https://s10.postimg.org/vpn50j48p/Screenshot_4.png" width="25%" height="25%" style="float:left; margin-right: 5px;"></a> </div>
      <div><a href="https://docs.google.com/document/d/1__BtIme5S2Yb0r_d1vUiFzr1pdfUv8TFktc-vt-hdg0/edit?usp=sharing"><img src="https://s10.postimg.org/itypbit3d/Screenshot_5.png" width="25%" height="25%" style="float:left; margin-right: 5px;"></a> </div>
      <div><a href="https://docs.google.com/document/d/1TWDKbVfO3cG1ifDhBPRbRMoAxcedwIsoGcfAebkVn_I/edit?usp=sharing"><img src="https://s10.postimg.org/e44jb4v21/Screenshot_6.png" width="25%" height="25%" style="float:left; margin-left: 200px; margin-top: 5px; margin-right: 5px;"></a> </div>
      <div><a href="https://docs.google.com/document/d/1zDFcgxvxa1382ER-Z7RjU4SPdlpGYRIsG9dXXxWgnFg/edit?usp=sharing"><img src="https://s9.postimg.org/cwrr7srtb/Screenshot_7.png" width="25%" height="25%" style="float:left; margin-left: 100px; margin-top: 5px;"></a> </div>
    </div>
    <div style="width:100%; height: 200px; background-color: #00dfff"> </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can You delete unnecessary code and add a working snippet?

Comment: Also you should probably learn to format your code, it's gonna make your life easier. It's difficult to read without indentation.

Comment: Perhaps clearing the floating (<- research that, if it means nothing to you) is all you need …?

Comment: Your problem is the float. You can achieve the same without float. Float is an old technique to layout, very problematic, and needs to be cleared continously (dirty CSS, dirty HTML). Right now, **`float` must be used only to floating elements, not for layout**. Try with display or flexbox.

Comment: Learn to use Stylesheets. Inline styling will make you soon wish to quit this job.

Comment: Also don't use `>` characters *as text* in HTML. Use their html representations like `&gt;` or `&lt;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cause you need to clear both side of floating divs before that:
like http://codepen.io/bra1N/pen/rrBkxd

```
<div style="clear: both"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used float:left; in the first div and float:right; in the second div. If you remove this the third div will not show up behind the divs.